# Extract pattern from `StringExpression`

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to extract a string that is book-ended by two strings. For example, given `<em> This is emphasized </em>`, I can find the whole string using a `StringExpression` of the form `"<em>"~~__~~"</em>"`. How do I extract the "`__`" part? I can hack it by using `StringDrop` if I know in advance the sizes of the bookends, but there should be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
StringCases["<em>tu tia mi tia</em>", "<em>" ~~ a__ ~~ "</em>" :> a]
{"tu tia mi tia"}
```